# Python - How can I stop redirect on a certain URL?

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2

I'm trying to write a program and I want it to let one redirect through but not allow another which contains "&key=". Is this possible in python? Having a massive headache trying to figure it out.

Comment: This might help - http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you mean by letting a redirect through?

Comment: I mean connecting to a url using urllib2 and then letting the first redirect to a new page happen, but when it tries to redirect to another (second page) then stop that from happening.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are interacting with URLs, but you can check if `&key=` is a substring of the URL you are using:

```
if "&key=" in in my_url_str:
     # do something
```

Or say if you are interacting with Request objects, you can use `Request.get_full_URL` and perform the same routine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The url isn't one I inputted its rather a redirection that I do not want to follow. I found a thread earlier explaining how to fully stop redirections within the script but I would like the first redirect to pass through and not allow the one containing that particular string through.